# scrape multiple urls from a csv file with R

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping

I have a CSV file that contains information about a set of articles and the 9th volume refers to the URLs. I have successfully scraped the title and abstract by a single URL with the following code:

```
library('rvest')
url <- 'https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10734-019-00404-5'
webpage <- read_html(url)

title_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.u-h1')
title_data <- html_text(title_data_html)
head(title_data)

abstract_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'#Abs1-content p')
abstract_data <- html_text(abstract_data_html)
head(abstract_data)

myTable = data.frame(Title = title_data, Abstract = abstract_data)
View(myTable)
```

Now I want to use R to scrape the title and abstract of each article. My question is how to import the URLs contained in the CVS file and how to write a for loop to scrape the data I need. I'm quite new to r so thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hey welcome! Since we don't know how your csv looks like can you provide the name of the csv and the name of the column that includes the URLs?

Comment: It seems this can easily be done by applying a function over the column containing your urls. Have a look at [`lapply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply). As @Yach mentioned, it'd be good if you could provide a few lines of the .csv through a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9046275).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
library(rvest)

URLs <- read.csv("urls.csv")
n <-nrow(URLs)
URLs2 <-character()

for (i in 1:n) {
  URLs2[i]<-as.character(URLs[i,1])

}

df <- data.frame(Row = as.integer(), Title=as.character(), Abstract=as.character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:n) {
  webpage <- tryCatch(read_html(URLs2[i]), error = function(e){'empty page'})
  if (!"empty page" %in% webpage) {
  title_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.u-h1')
  title_data <- html_text(title_data_html)
  abstract_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'#Abs1-content p')
  abstract_data <- html_text(abstract_data_html)
  temp <- as.data.frame(cbind(Row = match(URLs2[i], URLs2), Title = title_data, Abstract = abstract_data))
  if(ncol(temp)==3) {
    df <- rbind(df,temp)
  }
}
}

View(df)
```

Edit: The code has been edited in such a way that it will work even if the urls are broken (skipping them). The output rows will be numbered with the entry's corresponding row number in the csv.

[image]